# Does Ubuntu 20.10 affect the bios of Lenovo laptops?

Tags: system-installation, 17.10, lenovo, bios, 20.10

I am interested in installing Ubuntu 20.10 on my Lenovo Y50-70 laptop but I read that the Ubuntu 17.10 version corrupts the bios of the Lenovo generation that I own. Has Ubuntu already fixed the error or is it still present? Should I ask the question here or do I have to contact Canonical?

Comment: That was fixed in Ubuntu 17.10.1 media; and has not re-occurred.  http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/artful/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 years is a very long time in computing.

Lenovo has a list of bugs: [CVE-2017-5703](https://support.lenovo.com/nl/en/solutions/ps500160-system-firmware-can-be-erased-or-corrupted-after-boot) seems to be the one you are referring to. Ubuntu has the same [CVE-2017-5703](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2017-5753).

> Systems with microprocessors utilizing speculative execution and branch prediction may allow unauthorized disclosure of information to an attacker with local user access via a side-channel analysis.
>
> From the Ubuntu security team
>
> Jann Horn discovered that microprocessors utilizing speculative execution and branch prediction may allow unauthorized memory reads via sidechannel attacks. This flaw is known as Spectre. A local attacker could use this to expose sensitive information, including kernel memory.

As you can see all versions that where around back then have a fix for this. All newer are no long affected.